# Unexplained Null reference with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting a null reference exception with this on the line below when I try to add what is a regular string to a list. I added the extra .

```
   PhotoUrls.Add(images[i].GetAttribute("href").ToString());
```

Even though when I hover over it in the debugger it is showing it as a string with a value in that line. Here's the full method for context.

```
  public static List<String> Process()
    {
        List<String> PhotoUrls = null;

        try
        {
            WaitForReady(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            driver.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0,4000);");
            var images = driver.FindElementsByCssSelector(".v1Nh3 a");
            

            for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
            {
                
                PhotoUrls.Add(images[i].GetAttribute("href").ToString());
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }


        return PhotoUrls;

    }
```

Comment: Can you talk us through what you think `List<String> PhotoUrls = null;` does?

Comment: images[i].GetAttribute("href") is already a string .toString() wouldn't do anything as well.

Comment: driver.FindElementsByCssSelector(".v1Nh3 a") your class name .v1Nh3 could be a dynamic value which is brittle as well.

Comment: The issue was - List<String> PhotoUrls = null; I had thought this line initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You list is not initialized. So when you call `Add` on a `null` object, a null reference occurs.

```
public static List<String> Process()
    {
        // Changed this line here
        List<String> PhotoUrls = new List<String>();

        try
        {
            WaitForReady(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            driver.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0,4000);");
            var images = driver.FindElementsByCssSelector(".v1Nh3 a");
            

            for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
            {
                
                PhotoUrls.Add(images[i].GetAttribute("href").ToString());
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }


        return PhotoUrls;

    }
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I had spent all day losing my mind over this. I thought - List<String> PhotoUrls = null; was enough to initialize.